# illegal hour value error while getting difference between two times using TIMEDIFF in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I am using mysql and Java. when iam executing query to get difference between two times using`TIMEDIFF` in mysql, it giving result as `'40:23:12'`. But when I am using that query in java, exception error coming as:

> illegal hour value '40'

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_act_time) FROM user_activity_log WHERE id=1;
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What's the value of `last_act_time`?

Comment: if `last_act_time` contains the time value (`HH:mm:ss`) then you should use `TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(),last_act_time)` I guess

Comment: The value of last_act_time is '2016-08-06 17:26:10'

Comment: The you should use `TIMESTAMPDIFF`

Comment: What do you expect from the query? The difference in hours? something like that?

Comment: Thanks for your response. TIMESTAMPDIFF is working but i want the acurate inactivity time up to seconds like '40:23:12' as a string. @1000111

Comment: Could you please show us your java code?

Comment: String inActivityTime = "";
PreparedStatement pt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_act_time) FROM user_activity_log WHERE id=1");
ResultSet resultSet = pt.executeQuery();
if(resultSet.next())
 inActivityTime = resultSet.getString(1);

Comment: From which line you got the error `illegal hour value '40'` in java?

Comment: During the execution of query in java i.e (ResultSet resultSet = pt.executeQuery();) - @1000111

Comment: `CAST(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_act_time) AS CHAR)`

Comment: Its worked. Thank you @eggyal.  Thank you all for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, this is a bug in MySql version 5.1.6.

Ref: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36051

To solve this issue,the result should be converted to string during the execution of query. This can be achieved by the following ways.

```
SELECT concat('',TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_act_time)) FROM user_activity_log WHERE id=1;
```

The concat will make it string so you can process it as string.

```
SELECT CAST(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_act_time) AS CHAR) FROM user_activity_log WHERE id=1;
```

as suggested by @eggyal